# Не стилизуется форма на сайте

Tags: html, css

Новичок в web, не кидайте помидорами)
Верстаю форму для сайта, которая должна выглядеть примерно так:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMeQr.png
Сори за качество, но суть вы поняли. Выходит у меня так:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbB83.png . Помогите, люди добрые!!!

Вот код:

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
body, html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Меню сверху*/

#checkbox-menu,
.toggle{
    display: none;
}

.menu{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    transition: background .2s linear;
}

.menu li a:hover{
    background: #ffcc01;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu li a.logo{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 240px;
    background: #ffcc01;
}

.menu li a.contacts{
    margin-right: 100px;
}

/*Это первая секция с главным экраном*/

.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.intro{
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.intro-img{
    background-image: url(img/room1.png);
    width: 965px;
    height: 640px;
    left: 200px;
}

.intro .intro-text{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 65px;
    right: 885px;
    top: 220px;
    color: #113034;
}

.intro-contacts{
    background-color: #ffcc01;
    max-width: 590px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 170px;
    top: 638px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}

.intro-contacts i{
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.intro-contacts a{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.tel{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.tel:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000;
}

/*2-я секция "Наша кампания"*/

.stats{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 130px;
}

.stats-line{
    display: flex;
}

.stats-text{
    padding: 40px;
}

.stats-text h2{
    font-size: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    color: #667477;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.stats-text p{
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 14.5px;
    line-height: 27px;
    color: #667477;
}

.square{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f6f5f4;
    margin: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.stats-square{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffcc01;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.square-text{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #667477;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*3-я секция с аппартаментами*/

.apartments{
    background: #f6f3f2;
    padding: 60px 0;
}

.apart h2{
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #667477;
}

.card{
    max-width: 348px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card-container{
    padding: 25px;
}

.card-info{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.card-info .money{
    flex: 18;
    color: #ffcc01;
}

.card-info i{
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.card-info span:first-child{
    margin-right: 18px;
}

.card:hover{
    
    background: #fafaf9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.cards{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row: 30px;
}

/*Форма*/

.apart input[type=text]{
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    border: none;
    background-image: url(img/search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 27px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 62px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #919eb1;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.apart input[type=submit]{
    width: 115px;
    border: none;
    background: #ffcc01;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.all{
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 52px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.buttons-search{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Nigga</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a5582b465d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>   
    <header>
        <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-menu">
            <label for="checkbox-menu">
                <ul class="menu touch">
                    <li><a class="logo" href="#">luxestate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Apartment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Agents</a></li>
                    <li><a class="contacts" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Join us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Getting started</a></li>

                </ul>
                <span class="toggle">☰</span>
            </label>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="intro wrapper">
            <div class="intro-img">
                <p class="intro-text">Find your New <br>
                Modern Apartment</p>
            </div>

            <div class="intro-contacts">
                <a class="tel" href="(000)1234-567"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>(000)1234-567</a>
                <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Melbourn, Australia</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="stats wrapper">
            <div class="stats-text">
                <h2>Our's Company <br> Statistics</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Molestias unde, ipsum eveniet voluptatibus veritatis non quidem totam, 
                    recusandae ex accusantium facilis aspernatur dolore inventore suscipit 
                    esse tenetur fugit consequatur quisquam itaque. Sed.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Molestias unde, ipsum eveniet voluptatibus veritatis non quidem totam, 
                        recusandae ex accusantium facilis aspernatur dolore inventore suscipit 
                        esse tenetur fugit consequatur quisquam itaque. Sed.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stats-num">
                <div class="stats-line">
                    <div class="square">
                        <span class="stats-square">7231</span>
                        <span class="square-text">Apartments</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="square">
                            <span class="stats-square">875431</span>
                            <span class="square-text">Square meters</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="stats-line">
                        <div class="square">
                            <span class="stats-square">12647</span>
                            <span class="square-text">Clients</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="square">
                                <span class="stats-square">24</span>
                                <span class="square-text">Countries</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="apartments">
            <div class="wrapper apart">
                <h2>More then 500+ <br> Apartments</h2>
                <div class="cards">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="img/room2.png" alt="Apart">
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                            <div class="card-info">
                                <div class="money">€3,500</div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>2BD</span>
                                    <span><i class="fas fa-shower"></i>2BA</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                            <img src="img/room3.png" alt="Apart">
                            <div class="card-container">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                                <div class="card-info">
                                    <div class="money">€2,700</div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>1BD</span>
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-shower"></i>2BA</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                                <img src="img/room4.png" alt="Apart">
                                <div class="card-container">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                                    <div class="card-info">
                                        <div class="money">€1,200</div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <span><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>1BD</span>
                                            <span><i class="fas fa-shower"></i>1BA</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                    <img src="img/room5.png" alt="Apart">
                                    <div class="card-container">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                                        <div class="card-info">
                                            <div class="money">€5,800</div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <span><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>3BD</span>
                                                <span><i class="fas fa-shower"></i>3BA</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card">
                                        <img src="img/room6.png" alt="Apart">
                                        <div class="card-container">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                                            <div class="card-info">
                                                <div class="money">€4,400</div>
                                                <div class="info">
                                                    <span><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>2BD</span>
                                                    <span><i class="fas fa-shower"></i>3BA</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <img src="img/room7.png" alt="Apart">
                                            <div class="card-container">
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
                                                <div class="card-info">
                                                    <div class="money">€3,100</div>
                                                    <div class="info">
                                                        <span><i class="fas fa-bed"></i>2BD</span>
                                                        <span><i class="fas fa-shower"></i>2BA</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-search">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search locations">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search">
                    </form>
                    <button class="all">View All Apartments</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуясь инструментами разработчика, в вашем браузере, можно найти и исправить все недочеты) Там же можно быстро найти нужный вам элемент, посмотреть его стили, и в браузере прописать нужные, после чего перенести их в ваш css файл. Если не стилизуется нужный элемент, значит просто работаете не с тем селектором, в инструментах разработчика можно все это посмотреть и выбрать нужный.